# Add id's to <p> using JavaScript or jQuery or Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angular

I have an HTML document that is dynamically generated.

It has a bunch of `<p>` tags that have text in it. I am trying to select the `<p>` when user clicks on that specific text. Unfortunately, I am not allowed to add ***ids*** to the `<p>` tags which I could use to select the specific block of the test.

So I need to find a way to dynamically add id's to the `<p>` tags using javascript or jQuery or angular.

I have seen some solutions which use jQuery `.attr("id", "newId")` but it needs a selector and I don't know what to use as a selector.

Can anyone suggest something?

Comment: show your code, what have you done so far?

Comment: I meant <p> tags

Comment: I have tried $(document).on("click", (event) => {$('select').attr("id", "newId");}

Comment: what do you want to achieve by adding ids?

Comment: We need to see how your code is generating the HTML.

Comment: Basically I wants to add charts to the text paragraphs when user clicks on the text. For this I need to identify the paragraph where the user has clicked and so I thought of dynamically adding ids and then use them to add the charts

Comment: If you know which `p` has been clicked, there is no need to add an ID.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this helps:

```
$(function(){
  $("p").on("click", function(){
    $(this).attr('id', 'value');
  });
})
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/mvKZBopcwuVqAJV7vq7j?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all and only the interested p elements are on the page, try this:

```
jQuery( 'p' ).on( 'click', function() {
  jQuery( this ).attr( 'id', 'yourID' );
} );
```

Of course you'll need some code to manage progressive ids as they need to be unique on the page.

To be more specific and give an example of making progressive ids, let's say all of your p elements are within a container:

```
<div id="target_paragraphs">
  <p>...some text 1..</p>
  <p>...some text 2..</p>
  <p>...some text 3..</p>
  <p>...some text 4..</p>
  ...
  <p>...some text n..</p>
</div>
```

you could use this script:

```
count = 0;

jQuery( '#target_paragraphs p' ).on( 'click', function() {
  jQuery( this ).attr( 'id', 'paragaraph_ID_' + count );
  count++;
} );
```

Answer (score -1):

Without looking at your code, we can't really see the problem, but as i understand it you need a click event on all `p` tags?
You can bind the event to all `p` tags like this:
$("p").click(function(event){});

inside the function, `this` will become the element you clicked.